# How to pass arguments to createAsyncThunk?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

[Accordingly to documentation](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk) I can send some params into createAsyncThunk

```
export const someCustomAsyncThunk = createAsyncThunk(
    'counter/customFetch',
    async (someParam, thunkAPI) => { //<-- someParam ?
        const response = await fetch('https://someapi');

        return await response.json();
    }
);
```

```
extraReducers: {
   [someCustomAsyncThunk.fulfilled.type]: (state, action) => {
     // state dispatching gonna be there
   },
```

And I have an action somewhere inside my render:

```
onClick={() => dispatch(someCustomAsyncThunk(38746))}
```

but I'm receiving an error: `Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.`

What did I missed?

Answer (score 4):

solution not obvious, but in general, all is need is just providing types for arguments:

```
export const someCustomAsyncThunk = createAsyncThunk(
    'counter/customFetch',
    async (someParam: number, thunkAPI) => { <-- put types here
```